# Why does "isinstance(numpy.float64,numbers.Real)" return False?

Tags: python, numpy

Under numpy 1.8.0, python 2.7.6, I tried running the following code:

```
>>> isinstance(numpy.float64, numbers.Real)
False
```

My understanding was that the numbers module is supposed to be a general purpose way to categorize objects that have various number-like functionality. numpy.float64 certainly has the semantics of a real number, so why haven't the numpy developers chosen to register numpy.float64 with the numbers ABC?

I can of course do the registration myself but I just wanted to check whether there is some good reason for this omission.

Comment: `issubclass(numpy.float64, numbers.Real)` → `True`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not creating an instance of `numpy.float64`:

```
>>> import numpy  
>>> import numbers
>>> numpy.float64
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> numpy.float64()
0.0
>>> isinstance(numpy.float64, numbers.Real)
False
>>> isinstance(numpy.float64(), numbers.Real) # Notice the () after numpy.float64
True
>>>
```

Instead, your current code is simply checking if the `numpy.float64` class itself is an instance of `numbers.Real`.  This will never be true.

---

Note that you get the same behavior for any number type:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(int, numbers.Real)
False
>>> isinstance(int(), numbers.Real)
True
>>> isinstance(float, numbers.Real)
False
>>> isinstance(float(), numbers.Real)
True
>>>
```